# Pomm Twig and relation

Tags: twig, pomm

For a project I'm using [pommbundle](https://github.com/pomm-project/pomm-bundle), it's perfect for generating entities with an existing database.

In my controller:

```php
$catalogues = $this->get('pomm')['my_db1']
    ->getModel('\AppBundle\Entity\MyDb1\PublicSchema\CatalogueModel')
    ->findAll();

return this->render(
    'SiteBundle:Default:homePage.html.twig',
    array('catalogues'=>$catalogues));
```

But how can I access the variable inside my view (`Twig`)

```
{% for catalogue in catalogues %} 
    {{dump(catalogue)}} --> value inside 
{% endfor %}
```

Result dump

```
Catalogue {#1132 ▼ 
    #container: array:13 [▼ 
        "ID" => 8 
        "Code" => "MATIÈRE PREMIÈRE" 
        "Actif" => true 
        "DateAjout" => DateTime {#1212 ▶} 
        "Index" => 0 
        "PriseCommande" => false 
        "Description" => "" 
        "Couleur" => "Green" 
        "CouleurText" => "#000000" 
        "Tarif" => null 
        "WebActif" => false 
        "WebTitre" => null 
        "WebDescription" => null ] 
    -status: 1 }
```

`catalogue.ID` (not working) `catalogue.container.ID` (not working)
with catalogue.get('ID') works but it's the best way?

*Other question*

If my entity has a relation, e.g. `WebActif -> relation with another table`, 
How to access Webactif because the dump returns only an ID.Do I have to create my own method?

Is it possible to show a basic example?

Comment: For your second question I would recommend to open a second topic since this can be developed differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Model::findAll` method returns an iterator on database results. When this iterator is traversed, it returns entities filled with converted values.

**Note:** you’d better not use upper case letters in your column names as it will lead to confusion and it **will not work** properly with Pomm flexible entities. (same applies for table names).

```
<dl>
{% if catalogues.isEmpty() %}
  <dt>No results found.</dt>
{% else %}
  <dt>There are {{ catalogues.count() }} results:</dt>
  {% for catalogue in catalogues %}
  <dd>{{ catalogue.code }} (added the {{ catalogue.date_ajout.format('d-m-Y') }}){% if catalogue.actif %} OK {% endif %}</dd>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</dl>
```

**Edit:** Since your comment says your database contains capitalized column names here is an additional explanation on how flexible entities work.

(Official documentation about flexible entities is [here](https://github.com/pomm-project/ModelManager/blob/2.0/documentation/model_manager.rst#flexible-entities))

When a flexible entity is hydrated by the iterator values, they are converted and then pushed with their name in the entity. This is why you can use the generic accessor `$entity->get('MyColumn')` because keys are preserved.

But flexible entities are strange beasts because they can change depending on the `SELECT` that decides the data sent to them. When such entity is created the getters and setters are virtually created using PHP’s `__get` and `__set` and `__call` functions.

This can seem weird but look at this example:

```php
<?php
$entity = new MyEntity(['first_name' = 'John', 'last_name' => 'Doe']);
$entity['first_name']; // calls $entity->getFirstName() which defaults to $this->get('first_name');
```

It is then possible to override default accessors:

```php
<?php
class MyEntity extends FlexibleEntity
{
    /*
    * Triggered by $entity['first_name'] 
    * or $entity->first_name
    */
    public function getFirstName(): string
    {
        return uc_words($this->get('first_name'));
    }

    public function getLastName(): string
    {
        return strtoupper($this->get('last_name'));
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return sprintf("%s %s", $this->getFirstName(), $this->getLastName());
    }
}
```

Then, in twig it is possible to simply do `{{ entity.name }}` to trigger the `getName` function.

As you can see, the column names are camel cased to create the virtual accessors, this operation can be reversed only if the original column names are in lower case.

Comment: {{ catalogue.code }} don't work with my code because i have a upper case in a name and i don't change that because the database is already creating but {{catalogue.get("Code")}} work for me

Comment: @greg the [else clause](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-else-clause) could be a good idea here to clarify your example.

Comment: @Sanpi the idea was to mention the existence of the handy `isEmpty` method but yes it is better to use the `else` clause :)

Comment: For information I did not create the base my work and realize a website with the existing database, I know that by convention we do not use capital letters in the names of fields or table but apparently people do not know.
Knowing that the database is used in an ERP it is impossible to change the names.

Comment: No worries, I remember someone with the same problem as you and he was happy with the generic getter.

Comment: Thanks you for your job, your bunddle  save my life ... I have create a new topic for the last question ;) with the pomm'tag